# How do you use special character ids from an API request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Consider the following AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.minecraftwiki.net/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&format=json',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(siResponse) {
        for(var ns in siResponse.query.namespaces) {
            if(siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id >= 0) {
                if(siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id != namespaces.length) {
                    break;
                }
                if(siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id === 0) {
                    namespaces[siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id] = 'Main';
                } else {
                    namespaces[siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id] = siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].&asterisk;;
                }
                movelog[siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id] = 0;
                protectlog[siResponse.query.namespaces[ns].id] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's the API response](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&format=json)

Now, I could just use .canonical and rename the ids 4 and 5 from the default "Project" to "Minecraft Wiki", but I would like to use the "*": value instead. Is that possible, or is this just a bad wiki setting?

Comment: You should really get rid of `async: false`. You don't need it. Really. Trust me.

Comment: I looked it up, because honestly I didn't know what that did. I just built off example ajax calls. json doesn't even support that lol. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `foo['*']` to access the field instead of `foo.*` which would be a SyntaxError.

So in your case it would be `siResponse.query.namespaces[ns]['*']`

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge: no, you cannot begin an id with an asterisk, number, or other special characters. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) post for more info.